# Calculate geographical distance between points within groups (using ifelse statement)

Tags: r, if-statement, distance, euclidean-distance, geosphere

Using R, I've been trying to use the distHaversine function to calculate the geographic distance between individuals sampled from different regions, however with the examples online I haven't been successful yet. My main issue is that I can't figure out how to extract the long and lat values from the same columns for both individuals (examples online often have these in column long1, lat1 and long2, lat2.

I figured it would be 'easiest' to create an ifelse statement where in a newly created column (geo_distance) the output is returned.

So my dataset looks like this:

```
round replicate mixID individual soil_ID lat long
1   1   5   10  1276    35.60852    -83.44736
1   1   5   12  1276    35.60852    -83.44736
1   1   6   5   1276    35.60852    -83.44736
1   1   6   8   1276    35.60852    -83.44736
2   2   15  4   963     42.03011    -73.13442
2   2   15  7   958     42.02849    -73.13483
2   2   16  5   963     42.03011    -73.13442
2   2   16  9   1305    37.37293    -80.51875
```

What I'm trying is to do is:

1. group by round, replicate and mixID,
2. check in the column 'soil_ID' if the soil_ID match in these groups
3. if soil_ID(individual 1) != soil_ID(individual 2): calculate the geo_distance based on the long and lat columns from these two corresponding rows (the two individuals with the same round, replicate and mixID) using the distHaversine function.
4. if soil_ID(individual 1) == soil_ID(individual 2), return zero in the column geo_distance

so something like:

```
df %>%
      group_by(round, replicate, mixID) %>%
      mutate(geo_distance = ifelse(soil_ID ind1 !=soil_ID ind2, distHaversine(c(long, lat soil_ID ind1), c(long, lat soil_ID ind2)), "0")
```

ps another method I tried out was based on this post: [Calculate the euclidean distance between points within grouped data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52414879/calculate-the-euclidean-distance-between-points-within-grouped-data)

```
poss_dist <- possibly(geosphere::distm, otherwise = 0)
df.mixes.spores %>%
  nest(long, lat, .key= "coords") %>%
  group_by(round, replicate, mixID) %>%
  mutate(prev_coords = lag(coords)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(geo_distance = map2_dbl(coords, prev_coords, poss_dist))
```

however, I got the error `` All elements of `...` must be named. Did you want `coords = c(long, lat)`? `` and am unsure how to fix this.

TIA!

EDIT

Each row corresponds to an `individual` (which all have a long+lat sampling point).

So, for example in the last two rows the individuals 5 and 9 are mixed (both have `mixID` 16)

```
round replicate mixID individual soil_ID  lat        long
2        2       16      5        963    42.03011   -73.13442
2        2       16      9        1305   37.37293   -80.51875
```

I have added the column `soil_ID` as an indicator whether the two individuals are from the same exact location or a different location.
If I then would use an ifelse statement and two rows from a single `mixID` have the same `soil_ID` (like in the first two rows) I can just return the value ‘zero’ in the output column.

So my expected output is the distance between these two rows.

Comment: Can you clarify on what your expected output is?  Can you sort the data by round and soil_id and then find distance between the row and the row below it?  (Is location constant for each soil_id?)

Comment: Hi Dave, I've updated my original post, hopefully it's more clear now

Comment: Eventually I got the distance using below:

I too had a column 'labeled' (with Yes and No for each mixID) in the frame which I ended up using to reshape it to wide format.

```
df.wide <- reshape(df,  idvar = "mixID", timevar = "labeled", direction = "wide")

df.wide$geoDist <- geodist::geodist_vec(
  x1 = df.wide$long.Y,
  y1 = df.wide$lat.Y,
  x2 = df.wide$long.N,
  y2 = df.wide$lat.N,
  paired = TRUE,
  measure = "haversine"
)

df.wide$geoDist <- df.wide$geoDist / 1000
df.wide$geoDist <- round(df.wide$geoDist ,digit=3)
```